# Curl : send email with attachment -> Error -> Warning: Illegally formatted content-type field

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, unix

Code:

```
SERVER='smtp.abc.com'
PORT='587'
USER='sender@gmail.com'
PASS='12134'
SENDER_ADDRESS="$USER"
SENDER_NAME='SENDER'
RECIPIENT_NAME='testname'
RECIPIENT_ADDRESS='n@gmail.com'
SUBJECT='status'
MESSAGE='Hi all,
'
ATTACHMENT_FILE='/home/ubuntu/aa/aa.log'
ATTACHMENT_TYPE="$(file --mime-type '$ATTACHMENT_FILE' | sed 's/.*: //')"


curl --ssl-reqd --url "smtp://$SERVER:$PORT" \
    --user "$USER:$PASS" \
    --mail-from "$SENDER_ADDRESS" \
    --mail-rcpt "$RECIPIENT_ADDRESS" \
    --header "Subject: $SUBJECT" \
    --header "From: $SENDER_NAME <$SENDER_ADDRESS>" \
    --header "To: $RECIPIENT_NAME <$RECIPIENT_ADDRESS>" \
    --form '=(;type=multipart/mixed' --form "=$MESSAGE;type=text/plain" \
    --form "file=@$ATTACHMENT_FILE;type=$ATTACHMENT_TYPE;encoder=base64" --form '=)'
```

I'm trying to send an email attachment but getting the below error:

```
Warning: Illegally formatted content-type field!
curl: option --form: is badly used here
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

Comment: What does `ATTACHMENT_TYPE` contain?

Comment: (By the way, [don't use upper case for your private variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization))

Comment: my attachment is log file which contain plain text "Error: Unable to access jarfile /home/ubuntu/aa/aa1.jar
~
"

Comment: Maybe read my comment again? What is the output from `file --mime-type '$ATTACHMENT_FILE' | sed 's/.*: //'`? (Hint: It will be `cannot open \`$ATTACHMENT_FILE' (No such file or directory)` because you used single quotes instead of double.)

Comment: o/p -> is  "cannot open `$ATTACHMENT_FILE' (No such file or directory)" but the aa.log file exist there

Answer (score 2):

The only non hard coded content-type, that curl is complaining about (`Warning: Illegally formatted content-type field!`) is your `ATTACHMENT_TYPE`

Try getting its content, it gives you an error:

```
>>> echo $ATTACHMENT_TYPE
cannot open `$ATTACHMENT_FILE' (No such file or directory)
```

Change the single quotes from your `ATTACHMENT_FILE` to double quotes and you should be fine:

```
ATTACHMENT_TYPE="$(file --mime-type "$ATTACHMENT_FILE" | sed 's/.*: //')"
```

Comment: Removing the quotes entirely is also wrong. See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: Well, if the file exists, that expression outputs a mime type without any spaces in it. And the accepted answer you mentioned said "I tend to always quote strings just out of habit since it's safer that way.". So, safer, doesn't mean is the only, and the right way.

Comment: No; read the link. If the file exists but its name contains whitespace or shell wildcard characters, the output is something else than you want; probably another error message. This is a common beginner mistake which you should spend time on learning to avoid.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying then mate, learned a new thing today. I'll update my answer